# merge/mix multiple audio using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to merge/mix multiple audio file into one single audio file using ffmpeg api, I googled a lot but didn't find any useful code samples, could anyone help to provide some guide on how to do this with ffmpeg apis?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure to check out [ask] in the Help Center for info on asking questions here on SO. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOX for this task. Check documentation http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html. FFMPEG is widely used for audio conversions from one format to another. SOX is the best library which is widely used for mixing or concatenating audios.